# Ifstream fails for unknown reason

Tags: c++, memory-management, binary, ifstream, pgm

I have a problem with the function used to read the pgm file format to the memory .

I used the sources in the following link http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS308/Code/ReadImage.cpp . You can find others in the same directory ; and some instructions in CS308 ; if you’re interested .

The problem is ifstream ifp fails ; and I think this piece of code maybe the reason ; but it looks fine with me .

Any ideas will be appreciated

```
charImage = (unsigned char *) new unsigned char [M*N];

 ifp.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(charImage), (M*N)*sizeof(unsigned char));

 if (ifp.fail()) {
   cout << "Image " << fname << " has wrong size" << endl;
   exit(1);
 }
```

Comment: When you say "ifp fails" do you mean it prints "Image *fname* has wrong size"?

Comment: Yes ; it is . I doubt this piece of code the most ; since all the parameters of the image are correct ; I checked .

Comment: You never open an actual file for `ifp`.

Comment: No ; I don't . I'm afraid the whole function is too long so I ain't copy all of it here . You can check the link I provided .

http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS308/Code/ReadImage.cpp

Comment: The file is not at all too long.

Comment: Oh ; sorry ; I just want it's simply . So please visit the link for the function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input file is not formatted properly. It should have enough data to fill charImage, but it doesn't, and this is why it's failing. Another possibility is that you are trying to run this code on windows, and need to open the file in binary mode.

Specifically (for the binary part) change:

```
 ifp.open(fname, ios::in);
```

to:

```
 ifp.open(fname, ios::in | ios::binary);
```

As an aside, it is generally inappropriate to cast the result of a new operator. Here, it's just redundant and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well ; I think nothing is wrong with the file format. I open it with irfanview and nothing seems wrong . I also tried a few images ; not only one .

AFAIK ; the cast is used because  the gray values (0-255) need unsigned char ; but ifstream::read need char to work

Comment: You're missing the point. It's already an `unsigned char *` when you use `new unsigned char`. It's redundant to cast it to `unsigned char *`. Also, have you tried the second part of my suggestion, which is that you need to open it in binary mode?

Answer (score 1):

Anything using `reinterpret_cast<...>()` looks suspicious to me, to say the least. It is probably not the root of the problem, though. My personal guess is that the root of the problem is running the code on a Windows machine and not opening the file in binary mode. Try using

```
std::ifstream in("filename", std::ios_base:::binary);
```

Since the code opening the file isn't part of the question it is just a wild guess, though.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion . Thanks :)